# IE9 change html ajax response

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin, ajaxform

I use jQuery Form Plugin, I send some data to server and then recieve HTML which I insert on my Page.

```
    $('form').ajaxForm({
        success: function(response) {  }
    });
```

response is some HTML. This HTML is not valid. So this is

```
<tr><td>some</td></tr>
```

FF and Chrome recieve same HTML which I send from server. But IE clears all

```
<tr> and <td>.
```

This is very bad. How can I fix it?

Comment: Make the HTML in the response valid...?

Comment: Yes if I add "table" tags to HTML it will recieve without changes. But this way is not good for me